# ListView Item - Generate column value based on criteria not part of Item's class

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

Suppose I've a simple model class:

```
public class Car
{
    public string Make { get; init; }
    public string Model { get; init; }
    public string Year { get; init; }
}
```

In my ViewModel, I've two lists:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Car> Cars { get; }
    public List<Car> CanBeSold { get; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        Car car1 = new() { Make = "Toyota", Model = "Corolla", Year = "2020" };
        Car car2 = new() { Make = "Honda", Model = "Civic", Year = "2021" };
        Car car3 = new() { Make = "Mitsubishi", Model = "Lancer", Year = "2017" };

        Cars = new();
        CanBeSold = new();

        Cars.Add(car1);
        Cars.Add(car2);
        Cars.Add(car3);

        CanBeSold.Add(car2);
    }
}
```

In my view, I'm bidining a `ListView` to the `Cars` collection:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Cars}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Make" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Make}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Model" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Model}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Year" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Year}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Can Be Sold"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

How can I also show a `Yes/No` based on if the `Car` is in the list `CanBeSold`?

[image: Screenshot]

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a `MultiBinding` that contains a Binding to the `CanBeSold` property of the parent view model and a Binding to the current Car element.

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Can Be Sold">
    <GridViewColumn.DisplayMemberBinding>
        <MultiBinding>
            <MultiBinding.Converter>
                <local:ListElementConverter/>
            </MultiBinding.Converter>
            <Binding Path="DataContext.CanBeSold"
                     RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}"/>
            <Binding />
        </MultiBinding>
    </GridViewColumn.DisplayMemberBinding>
</GridViewColumn>
```

The Binding Converter checks if the element is contained in the list:

```
public class ListElementConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(
        object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return values.Length == 2 &&
            values[0] is IList list &&
            list.Contains(values[1])
            ? "Yes"
            : "No";
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(
        object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do as follows: I would create a new class **CarExt**, in which I would include class **Car**, as well as an additional get property "can the car be sold", which is calculated by finding the car in list **CanBeSold**. And I would bind class **CarExt** to the *ListView ItemsSource*.